# Python SUDS TypeNotFound with complex type whose name starts with "__"

Tags: python, soap, suds

I've encountered another dreaded TypeNotFound error with Python SUDS (Python 2.7, suds-jurko==0.6)

these are relevant parts of XSD:

```xml
<xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="requestHeader">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="type" type="tns:requestType"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="userID" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sessionID" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="requestType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="__value" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

WSDL correctly imports XSD, so I don't believe Doctor would help:

```xml
<wsdl:definitions 
    name="FooBarService" 
    targetNamespace="foo.bar.ns" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:tns="foo.bar.ns" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<import namespace="foo.bar.ns" schemaLocation="someschemafile.xsd"/>
<import namespace="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array" schemaLocation="someschemafile2.xsd"/>
```

And `someschemafile.xsd`:

```xml
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array" 
    xmlns:tns="foo.bar.ns" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="unqualified" 
    targetNamespace="foo.bar.ns">
```

Then I create `requestHeader` and `requestType`:

```python
q = soap_client.factory.create('requestHeader')
print q

(requestHeader){
    type = 
    (requestType){
        __value = None
    }
    userID = None
    sessionID = None
}
```

And then:

```
q.type = soap_client.factory.create('requestType')
q.type.__value = 42
q.userID = "foo"
q.sessionID = "bar"
print q

(requestHeader){
    type = 
        (requestType){
            __value = 42
        }   
    userID = "foo"
    sessionID = "bar"
}
```

and then I try to call method that uses `requestHeader`, after which I get:

```
TypeNotFound(u"Type not found: '__value'",)
```

I'd also tried this:

```
q = {
    'type': 42,
    'userID':  "foo",
    'sessionID':  "bar"
}
```

But this renders wrong SOAP message:

```xml
<header>
    <type>42</type>
    <userID>foo</userID>
    <sessionID>bar</sessionID>
</header>
```

instead of

```xml
<header>
    <type>
        <__value>42</__value>
    </type>
    <userID>foo</userID>
    <sessionID>bar</sessionID>
</header>
```

Which is in the end refused by service.

I'm sorry I can't provide whole WSDL and XSD, they are restricted.

What can I do to make suds create correct SOAP XML with `__value` element?

I'm using local copy of WSDL, so I am able to change it, as long a it results in correct SOAP XML. Still, I wouldn't know what to change.

Edit: Added somewhat cleaned traceback (removed stuff before SUDS method is called) `request` is SUDS object where one of the attributes is of type `requestHeader`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FooClientClass                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8ccf453fe073> in <module>()
----> 1 soap_client.service.someServiceMethod(request)

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    519         client = clientclass(self.client, self.method)
    520         try:
--> 521             return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
    522         except WebFault, e:
    523             if self.faults():

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.pyc in invoke(self, args, kwargs)
    574         timer.start()
    575         binding = self.method.binding.input
--> 576         soapenv = binding.get_message(self.method, args, kwargs)
    577         timer.stop()
    578         metrics.log.debug("message for '%s' created: %s", self.method.name,

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/bindings/binding.pyc in get_message(self, method, args, kwargs)
    107         content = self.headercontent(method)
    108         header = self.header(content)
--> 109         content = self.bodycontent(method, args, kwargs)
    110         body = self.body(content)
    111         env = self.envelope(header, body)

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/bindings/document.pyc in bodycontent(self, method, args, kwargs)
     93 
     94         parse_args(method.name, self.param_defs(method), args, kwargs,
---> 95             add_param, self.options().extraArgumentErrors)
     96 
     97         return root

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/argparser.pyc in parse_args(method_name, param_defs, args, kwargs, external_param_processor, extra_parameter_errors)
     81     """
     82     arg_parser = _ArgParser(method_name, param_defs, external_param_processor)
---> 83     return arg_parser(args, kwargs, extra_parameter_errors)
     84 
     85 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/argparser.pyc in __call__(self, args, kwargs, extra_parameter_errors)
    106         self.__init_run(args, kwargs, extra_parameter_errors)
    107         try:
--> 108             self.__process_parameters()
    109             return self.__all_parameters_processed()
    110         finally:

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/argparser.pyc in __process_parameters(self)
    297         """Collect values for given web service operation input parameters."""
    298         for pdef in self.__param_defs:
--> 299             self.__process_parameter(*pdef)
    300 
    301     def __push_frame(self, ancestry_item):

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/argparser.pyc in __process_parameter(self, param_name, param_type, ancestry)
    292         self.__stack[-1].process_parameter(param_optional, value is not None)
    293         self.__external_param_processor(param_name, param_type,
--> 294             self.__in_choice_context(), value)
    295 
    296     def __process_parameters(self):

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/bindings/document.pyc in add_param(param_name, param_type, in_choice_context, value)
     84             # Construct request data for the current input parameter.
     85             pdef = (param_name, param_type)
---> 86             p = self.mkparam(method, pdef, value)
     87             if p is None:
     88                 return

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/bindings/document.pyc in mkparam(self, method, pdef, object)
    128                 tags.append(self.mkparam(method, pdef, item))
    129             return tags
--> 130         return Binding.mkparam(self, method, pdef, object)
    131 
    132     def param_defs(self, method):

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/bindings/binding.pyc in mkparam(self, method, pdef, object)
    223         content = Content(tag=pdef[0], value=object, type=pdef[1],
    224             real=pdef[1].resolve())
--> 225         return marshaller.process(content)
    226 
    227     def mkheader(self, method, hdef, object):

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/core.pyc in process(self, content)
     57         if isinstance(content.value, Property):
     58             root = self.node(content)
---> 59         self.append(document, content)
     60         return document.root()
     61 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/core.pyc in append(self, parent, content)
     70         log.debug('appending parent:\n%s\ncontent:\n%s', parent, content)
     71         if self.start(content):
---> 72             self.appender.append(parent, content)
     73             self.end(parent, content)
     74 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/appender.pyc in append(self, parent, content)
     86                 appender = candidate_appender
     87                 break
---> 88         appender.append(parent, content)
     89 
     90 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/appender.pyc in append(self, parent, content)
    227         for item in object:
    228             cont = Content(tag=item[0], value=item[1])
--> 229             Appender.append(self, child, cont)
    230 
    231 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/appender.pyc in append(self, parent, content)
    166         @type content: L{Object}
    167         """
--> 168         self.marshaller.append(parent, content)
    169 
    170 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/core.pyc in append(self, parent, content)
     70         log.debug('appending parent:\n%s\ncontent:\n%s', parent, content)
     71         if self.start(content):
---> 72             self.appender.append(parent, content)
     73             self.end(parent, content)
     74 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/appender.pyc in append(self, parent, content)
     86                 appender = candidate_appender
     87                 break
---> 88         appender.append(parent, content)
     89 
     90 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/appender.pyc in append(self, parent, content)
    227         for item in object:
    228             cont = Content(tag=item[0], value=item[1])
--> 229             Appender.append(self, child, cont)
    230 
    231 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/appender.pyc in append(self, parent, content)
    166         @type content: L{Object}
    167         """
--> 168         self.marshaller.append(parent, content)
    169 
    170 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/core.pyc in append(self, parent, content)
     70         log.debug('appending parent:\n%s\ncontent:\n%s', parent, content)
     71         if self.start(content):
---> 72             self.appender.append(parent, content)
     73             self.end(parent, content)
     74 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/appender.pyc in append(self, parent, content)
     86                 appender = candidate_appender
     87                 break
---> 88         appender.append(parent, content)
     89 
     90 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/appender.pyc in append(self, parent, content)
    227         for item in object:
    228             cont = Content(tag=item[0], value=item[1])
--> 229             Appender.append(self, child, cont)
    230 
    231 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/appender.pyc in append(self, parent, content)
    166         @type content: L{Object}
    167         """
--> 168         self.marshaller.append(parent, content)
    169 
    170 

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/core.pyc in append(self, parent, content)
     69         """
     70         log.debug('appending parent:\n%s\ncontent:\n%s', parent, content)
---> 71         if self.start(content):
     72             self.appender.append(parent, content)
     73             self.end(parent, content)

/home/user/.virtualenvs/foo_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/literal.pyc in start(self, content)
     84             content.type = self.resolver.find(name, content.value)
     85             if content.type is None:
---> 86                 raise TypeNotFound(content.tag)
     87         else:
     88             known = None

TypeNotFound(u"Type not found: '__value'",)
```

Comment: "and then I try to call method that uses requestHeader, after which I get:" please show the method you are calling.

Comment: What you must keep in mind is that class variables starting with double underscores like `__variable` are meant to be private to the class in python (they are actually mangled not truly private) and this might be the reason for your difficulties. I would say stop using the double underscore or use one underscore instead if you must. Getting through the hoops of using mangled names is possible but its really messy and not pythonic and I would discourage it outright.

Comment: Yeah, I know about double underscores in Python, but... I'm not the author of requested SOAP API, I'm just consuming it... And that thing is enterprise Java monster where double underscore names mean nothing... I'll see if I can do something to prevent name mangling in Python, maybe this is why SUDS gets confused. Thnx

Comment: @dopstar : I can't really show the whole method, but it is something like this: soap_client.service.someMethod(soap_object_with_request_header)

Comment: Something like what? Dont show how the method is being implemented, I understand. Just show how you are calling it. Or just show the full traceback error message because it will show there instead of showing the final error message. That kind of information is rather useful im afraid. Unless the traceback is also "restricted" :)

Comment: @dopstar you're right, I've added traceback...

Comment: Oh I see, this is a bug in the jurko suds library. See bug: https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds/issues/48/underscore-parameters-dont-work  . The bug is still open so the plot thickens for you. You either wait for the solution to come or fix the library and provide patch to that bug (recommended). Your patch would handle variables with underscores (protected) and with double underscores (private/mangled) and everyone will live happily ever after. Im interested in solving this but I dont have sample data to get started in patching. Everyone is cagey with their apis. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As per @dopstar comment, this happens because of bug in SUDS. Since I have no time for trying to fix it on the source, I have devised somewhat ugly workaround

```python
from lxml import etree

etree_object = build_XML_using_etree()

soap_client.service.someServiceMethod(
    __inject={'msg': etree.tostring(etree_object)}
)
```

The ugly part is actually not visible here it is the logic of knitting the XML hidden behind `build_XML_using_etree` method since we can't rely on SUDS doing it here.

On the other hand, once raw XML is injected into SUDS stack, everything else works nicely, so maybe this is not so bad...